# Abstract class inheriting another abstract class in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class which has a pure virtual function declared, like this:

```
class A : public virtual B
{
public:

   virtual void setOn() = 0;

   virtual void setOff() = 0;
};
```

Now, class B is also abstract:

```
class B
{
public:

   virtual const ElementId& getElementId() const = 0;

   virtual const std::string& getName() const = 0;

   virtual ~B();

};
```

My question is how class A can be valid, since it does not provide the implementation of the pure virtual methods in class B?

Comment: It is an abstract class, you cannot create an instance of it - so why would you need to implement other virtual functions?

Comment: I do not know, but the code base which I am working with has this structure, so I am just curious how it is possible.

Comment: `A` inherits `B`'s pure virtual functions and they become pure virtual in `A`, which makes `A` abstract irrelevant of any pure virtual functions it provides itself.

Comment: Designing class hierarchies would be really inconvenient if every pure virtual function had to be implemented immediately when inheriting one level down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A class that inherits from an abstract class does not have to implement the pure virtual methods. Not doing so it becomes an abstract class itself which means in this case that `A` is also an abstract class regardless of other pure virtual methods declared in `A`.